# Array structure / syntax (turns out the real q was about classes, didn't know the term.)

Tags: javascript, arrays

is my understanding of arrays inside of arrays is built like this?

```
a = new Array[
b = new Array[
c = new Array[
something,
something.more,
something.more.to,
something.more.to.learn
]]];
```

or does it need to be

```
a = new Array[];
a.b = new Array[];
a.b.c = new Array[
a.b.c.something,
a.b.c.something.more,
a.b.c.something.more.to,
a.b.c.something.more.to.learn
];
```

or am I as lost as I think I am.

Comment: Yes, I think you're pretty lost. Are you trying to apply semantics of a different programming language to JavaScript?

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: edit: I am editing and existing javascrit program.I am sorry, I tring to teach myself javascript, (which seesm to be utilizing some c++), and I want to edit this page to add more functions to it, but I cant quite grasp what this.stuff is and why JSHint keeps kicking back errors about poor array literation.

Comment: Start with a beginner's tutorial. You're basically asking a very broad question *"how does JavaScript syntax work"*. Clearly that's going to be too much to answer here.

Comment: [MDN Learn JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn/javascript) has links to various resources.

Comment: thanks for the resources, I love resources, only problem is, I click don a link that said learn javascript interactively, signed up and bam, how to build a web page, I dont want to build web pages. I want to just learn pure javascript. any help on those resources.

Comment: There are several links on that page, and many other resources online. Guessing at how a language works and then asking for help when it fails isn't the way to learn. Try the *Eloquent JavaScript* link

Comment: I am sorry, I "guess" there is no where to learn pure javascript without libraries or html, because thats all that on that page so far.Eleoquent javascript is not opening Finally opend, this is perfect no how to say hello world on a web page. im just hoping there os no foo.bar

Comment: It seems like you are looking for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide , specifically https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Array_Object. Of course you can learn about JavaScript, the language. Only because you haven't found the resources doesn't mean they don't exist ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to differentiate between arrays and objects.
You may use arrays like so:

```
var nested = new Array(
    new Array( '1.1', '1.2' ),
    new Array( '2.1', '2.2' ),
);
```

Or use the short syntax:

```
var nested = [ [ '1.1', '1.2' ], [ '2.1', '2.2' ] ];
```

But you can't access array items by a textual index like in PHP or the like, you need to refer to the numbered index to call the different elements.

```
// Alert the first value of the second array in nested.
// Note that array indeces start off on zero.
alert( nested[ 1 ][ 0 ] ); // -> 2.1
```

If you need to reference the different elements you have to use objects:

```
var nested = {
    first: {
        a: '1.1',
        b: '1.2'
    },
    second: {
        a: '2.1',
        b: '2.2'
    }
}

alert( nested.second.a ); // -> 2.1
```

Comment: Ok, the reference the elements and object is more along the lines of what I am trying to do. I read somewhere that starting any type of array with () is not correct, but that's all i see In this program, is there a version or variant issue with this.

Comment: Well you can basically choose wether you want to use the short syntax or not. Both ways are correct, and using the short syntax is even faster then new Array().

Answer (score 0):

You can define multi-dimensional arrays a couple different ways but if you want inline, this would be a very simple way. (This is just a random structure for example purposes)

```
var arr = 
    [
      ["a"],
      [
        ["b"],
        [],
        [
          ["c"]
        ]
      ],
      [
        [],
        []
      ]
    ];
```

Things get really hard to follow but just treat each tab in as a sub dimension of the parent array.

To access any element you would use indexes

```
arr[0][0]; // "a"
arr[1][0][0]; // "b"
arr[1][2][0][0]; // "c"
```

This really helps when you have intracate structures where delcaring new Array(...) would get very chained and complicated.